# tensorflow addon moving average

Tags: tensorflow, moving-average

Does this implementation (https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/MovingAverage) is the same as ExponentialMovingAverage in tensorflow train module (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ExponentialMovingAverage)?

```
import tensorflow as tf

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5)
loss_obj = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()

@tf.function
def train_step(inputs, outputs):

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        start, end = model([inputs[0], inputs[1], inputs[2]], training=True)
        start_truth, end_truth = tf.squeeze(outputs[0]), tf.squeeze(outputs[1])
        start_loss = loss_obj(start_truth, start)
        end_loss = loss_obj(end_truth, end)
        total_loss = start_loss + end_loss

    model_gradients = tape.gradient(total_loss, model.trainable_variables)
    opt_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(model_gradients, model.trainable_variables))

    ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.9999)
    with tf.control_dependencies([opt_op]):
        ema.apply(model.trainable_variables)

    del tape
    return total_loss, start_loss, end_loss
```

is the same as

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

optimizer = tfa.optimizers.MovingAverage(Adam(learning_rate=5e-5))
loss_obj = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()

@tf.function
def train_step(inputs, outputs):

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        start, end = model([inputs[0], inputs[1], inputs[2]], training=True)
        start_truth, end_truth = tf.squeeze(outputs[0]), tf.squeeze(outputs[1])
        start_loss = loss_obj(start_truth, start)
        end_loss = loss_obj(end_truth, end)
        total_loss = start_loss + end_loss

    model_gradients = tape.gradient(total_loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(model_gradients, model.trainable_variables))

    del tape
    return total_loss, start_loss, end_loss
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementations are not equivalent. Your first implementation creates shadow variables that are stored in the GraphKeys.MOVING_AVERAGE_VARIABLES and GraphKeys.ALL_VARIABLES collection. This version should only be used within the tf.compat.v1.estimator.Estimator framework or in the context of tf.compat.v1.train.
In your second implementation the shadow variables are stored in slots created by the optimizer and are updated during the call optimizer.apply_gradients. It is straightforward to swap average and non-average model weights for evaluation and for saving models.